React useState state doesn't change
I am new to React.
I have a tabs list in App.js:
const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([
{id:0, name:"TOS", content:(<WelcomeTab title='title' isChecked={isTosChecked} setIsChecked={setIsTosChecked}/>), unviewed:0, visible:false}, 
......
])

Also I have a checkbox component that works perfectly. <WelcomeTab/> has one inside.
I need to access that checkbox state from App.js, so I have const [isTosChecked, setIsTosChecked] = useState(false) in App.js.
But when I am trying to press checkbox state isn't changing.
I have tried to put <WelcomeTab/> directly in to the render of App.js and it works just fine. But when it is located in the tabs list and rendering like that
{tabs.map(tab => 
  <div key={tab.id} className={tab === activeTab ? "tab selected" : "tab"}>
    {tab.content}
  </div>
)}

pressing the checkbox isn't changing the state.
After debugging I figured out, that I can't change (nothing happens, isChecked var isn't changing) the state from either WelcomeTab or Checkbox in case of using tabs list.

See related codesandbox with console.logs explaining whats going on.
You pass JSX to the initial state which is evaluated exactly once during initial render.
You click and change isTosChecked, which updates the variable and causes a parent re-render, affecting the children as well. But the tabs state didnt change - the initialValue is not evaluated again (i.e. whatever goes into useState as an initial argument).
Since tabs didn't change (also consider that changes to non-primitive states are evaluated by reference), the data that the jsx displays is stale.
Most generally, i would not recommend doing what you did. It is very strange to nest JSX inside state (where the jsx holds other state also). My codesandbox does NOT reflect the best practice.
You could use const tabs = [...] without the state, since state is used when you want to trigger a re-render with data that is subject to change - but the jsx is just static data (taking state into their props, causing rerenders anyway). It should get whatever it needs to do its job via props which can be state.
